# On before login event

Tags: magento

I'm trying to make a check before I let the client login in my shop.
I have searched on google, with 0 results, for an observer/event before login.

The ideea is simple: The user enters credentials, hits enter and then I'll make the check. If check returns false: break; the login proccess.

Does anyone have any ideeas?

Answer (score 0):

Use predispatch event of the customer account controller for your observer:

```
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to write a event observer for this :

Register the event for customer login in your module's `config.xml`

```
<customer_login>
<observers>
    <yourobservername>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
        <method>customerLogin</method>
    </yourobservername>
</observers>
```

Your observer class would look like this:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        // your checking code here
    }
}
```